# onpaste event handler not cancelled in shadowroot

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

As an example, I am trying to disable users from allowing paste on bing.com using a chrome extension (content-script).

The javascript is extremely simple.

```
document.onpaste = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
};
```

This works fine on the main bing.com search page for input fields. However, If i go to chat option (which opens in a **shadowroot**, my paste function is called but continues to paste the content in the textarea of chat.

I have tried disabling the copy options which works well in both main dom and shadowroot.

```
    document.addEventListener(
    "copy",
    (evt) => {
        evt.clipboardData.setData(
            "text/plain",
            "Copy is disabled"
        );
        evt.preventDefault();
    },
    false
);
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

**EDIT:**

You can refer to the below source repository for reproducing the same.
https://github.com/godwinpinto/test-extension

Comment: Can you use the [<>] button in the StackOverflow editor to convert the code in your post to a [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for highlighting, have added a sample repository to test the given scenario

Comment: Works for me when pasting that code in the console.

Comment: @Kaiido The goal is to stop pasting in the textarea of bing's chat window, which is shadow root. (currently i am using the chrome extension)

Comment: Yes, that I understood, and I'm saying that when I paste the `document.onpaste = ...` code in my browser's console for that page, it correctly prevents pasting in the textarea there. So the issue is probably in your extension's execution.